# Can my isp see the (non-https) websites I visit if I use browser VPN extension?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, isp

Can my isp see the (non-https) websites I visit if I use browser VPN extension?

Chrome notices non-secure connection for them but I use browser based VPN extension and different country (VPN server).

Comment: Could you please be more specific what browser VPN extension that is? In general they should do their job of hiding the destination from the ISP (see the many similar questions here) but misconfigurations also happen often and sometimes the provider of the VPN is the one who you should trust even less than the ISP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually connected to a VPN (just using an extension may not be enough, you may need to activate it or log into the VPN server or something as well) then no, your ISP cannot see the sites you visit, even non-https sites, **if you use a good VPN**. Apparently a surprisingly large number of VPN services out there rely on your local configuration to look up websites through DNS queries, usually to your ISP. So if you don't [choose your VPN carefully](https://thatoneprivacysite.net/#detailed-vpn-comparison) then you could easily leak information about what domains you visit, even while using a VPN.

Either way, Chrome is not your ISP. Chrome is your browser. Chrome knows every site you visit, and especially if you are logged into the browser, so does Google.